# Pegar link da tag <a> com javascript. Para script de menu ativo

Tags: javascript, html

Estou fazendo um template e preciso colocar a página ativa com cor diferente dos outros botões. Para isto eu preciso pegar o conteúdo de um  e comparar com o link da página.

Se for igual eu coloco uma nova classe no botão aonde irá puxar o css do menu ativo.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function mostrarAtivo(tag){
    var tag_li = document.getElementById('lista_menu');
    var tag_a = tag_li.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (i=0; i<tag_a.length; i++ )
    {
      /* pegar o link da tag a e compara com o link da página, se for igual o link é o link ativo
 (recebe uma classe chamada "active"). */
    } 
  }
</script>
```

Bom não precisa colocar o script inteiro, só quero saber como pega o link dentro de uma tag :

```
<a href="">
```

Procurei na internet porém não consegui achar, agora se vocês quiserem colocar o script inteiro seria melhor. Porém só precisa explicar como pega o link de pegar o link do a que o resto eu sei fazer e depois que eu fizer eu posto aqui a resposta completa.

Comment: Que linguagem server-side você está usando ?

Comment: estou utilizando o twig, http://twig.sensiolabs.org/
É a linguagem que eles usam para a API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
document.getElementById("seuID").href;
```

ou

```
document.getElementById("seuID").getAttribute("href");
```

No seu caso:

```
var tag_li = document.getElementById('lista_menu');
var tag_a = tag_li.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i=0; i<tag_a.length; i++ )
{
    vars = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].getAttribute("href");
    console.log(vars);
}
```

Comment: Vou testar para ver, porém acredito que teria que ser por getElementByTagName

Comment: No seu caso, sim. Mas no geral costuma-se usar class ou id para identificar o elemento. Só indiquei o que eu costumo usar. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Como dito anteriormente, aqui está o script que falei que iria postar.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var tag_li = document.getElementById('lista_menu');
  var tag_a = tag_li.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (i=0; i<tag_a.length; i++ )
  {
    console.log(tag_a.length);
    console.log(i);
    vars = tag_li.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].getAttribute("href");
    console.log(vars);
    vars2 = window.location.href;
    console.log(vars2);
    if (vars == vars2){
      console.log("achou");
      tag_li.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].parentNode.id = "li";
    }
  }
</script>
```

O console.log é só para ter uma idéia do funcionamento do script na hora do teste.

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer assim para comparar e saber se um link é o mesmo que a página em que estás:
<sub>(porém isto deve ser feito no servidor. Fazer no JavaScript é corrigir no sítio errado)</sub>

```
function mostrarAtivo(tag) {
    var tags = document.querySelectorAll('#lista_menu a');
    var url = location.pathname;
    for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        var link = tags[i].href;
        if (url.indexOf(link) != -1) tags[i].classList.add('active');
    }
}
```

Os passos são:

>Ir buscar todas as ancoras dentro de `#lista_menu`
> ir buscar o endereço atual (url)
> iterar as tags todas
> verificar se o `href` de cada tag faz parte do url da página atual.

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver usando alguma linguagem server side... PHP, por exemplo, dá para utilizar assim.

```
    # http://localhost/meusite/pagina.php

    $Url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; # pagina.php

?>
<ul>
    <li <?php $class = ($url == 'pagina.php') ? 'current' : '' ?><a href="pagina.php">Link 1</a></li>
    <li <?php $class = ($url == 'pagina-1.php') ? 'current' : '' ?><a href="pagina-2.php">Link 2</a></li>
    <li <?php $class = ($url == 'pagina-2.php') ? 'current' : '' ?><a href="pagina-3.php">Link 3</a></li>
    <li <?php $class = ($url == 'pagina-3.php') ? 'current' : '' ?><a href="pagina-4.php">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Estou utilizando uma API da Xtech, então a pessoa cadastra o menu em um sistema em um painel de admin. Logo a melhor solução seria em Javascript mesmo. (Já que eu não sei qual vai ser o nome do menu)